# Access an object from listener

Tags: java, listener

Let's say we have some `Foo` class that contains

```
public void setOnSomethingListener(OnSomethingListener listener);
```

We register it with:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setOnSomethingListener(new OnSomethingListener(){
  public void onSomething(String data) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Is it possible to access from `onSomething` method parental object that has registered mentioned listener without accessing defined `foo` value ?

I ask about it because I would like to assign this listener to some parameter and register it in the few objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

What you are doing here is defining an **anonymous inner class**. You can access attributes and methods of the containing class by doing.

```
MyContainingClass.this.attributeName
```

Comment: AKA [Qualified `this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4)

Comment: What about if used listener is not inside `MyContainingClass` ? For example - object that registers listener is `EditText` type and listener is `View.OnFocusChangeListener`. I got warning: `android.widget.EditText is not an enclosing class`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
OnSomethingListener.this.*
```