# Acess non final object from listener

Tags: java, properties, listener

I have an ArrayList of Foo, whereas foo have an Bar IntegerProperty and a String BarName.

What I want is to access the object Foo from the listener and then change the BarName, something like:

```
for(String b : BarNameList){
    Foo f = new Foo();
    f.setBarName(b);
    f.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>(){
                    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> o,
                            Number oldVal, Number newVal) {
                            // I need to get which f is from the FooList here
                            // So I can, for example:
                            f.setBarName(f.getBarName() + newVal);
                    }
                  });
    FooList.add(f);
}
```

I got an error since my f is not final.

From what I understand [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522546/access-an-object-from-listener) is related and with the suggested methods there I get:

**No enclosing instance of the type Foo is accessible in scope.**

How can I get this instance of f in the `changed()` method?

Comment: Why don't you declare Foo as final?  final Foo f = new Foo();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access variable f from in the `changed()` method of your anonymous class unless you define it as final.

```
final Foo f = new Foo();
```